# Vote count tooltip has too much margin - "View upvote and downvote totals."

Tags: bug, design, tooltips, vote-count

There's too much margin on the right of the vote count tooltip that reads *"View upvote and downvote totals."*

[image: screenshot of vote count tooltip]

Comment: There's too much margin pretty much everywhere on this website.

Comment: That’s not margin. The tooltip has a specific width and the text flows into two lines.

Comment: `.wmx2 { max-width: 16.2051282rem !important; }` is responsible for this line-wrap, removing the max-width would fix this particular case, but not knowing how many other tool-tips have class `.wmx2`, it might not be a solution... also: didn't check how removing max-width would influence the tool-tip on small devices